# How to render specific json response data fields on frontend web using django

Tags: json, django

I am using django with templates and trying to send my json response data to the frontend web page. But in the frontend ui i want to show only specific fields of the json response data which i am unable to figure out. Right now i can send the complete json response data and show it in the frontend web page.

Here is my code details -

This function connects to my backend index and gets each document from index and appends it to jsonitems dictionary.

```
def sampledata(request):
    samplecount = requests.get(sampleindex + "/_count", auth=auth, verify=sslcheck)
    print(samplecount.json()['count'])
    count = samplecount.json()['count']
    
    jsonitems = {}
    for item in range(count):
        data = requests.get(sampleindex + "/_doc/" + str(item), auth=auth, verify=sslcheck)
        jsondata = data.json()
        jsonitems[item] = jsondata
    print(jsonitems)
    context = {'jsonitems': jsonitems}

    return render(request, 'samplewebapp/sampledata.html', context)
```

This is the template view which i am using to render on the frontend web ui.

```
{% if jsonitems %}
    <ul>
    {% for k, v in jsonitems.items %}
    <table>
    <tr><th> Sample data Item </th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ v }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No CVE data available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Currently table data 'v' (ie value) shows the complete json data. But i want to show only specific fields from the json data on the frontend (as in v['year'] and v['title'] should show me year and title respectively).

eg. JSON response data

```
{
  "year": 2013,
  "title": "Monica Z",
  "info": {
    "directors": [
      "Per Fly"
    ],
    "release_date": "2013-09-13T00:00:00Z",
    "rating": 7.3,
    "genres": [
      "Biography",
      "Drama",
      "Music"
    ],
    "image_url": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODA5NzUyNDA0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODY5MjQwMDE@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
    "plot": "Ambitious singer must struggle with her musical career, her love life and to bring up her daughter by herself.",
    "rank": 4957,
    "actors": [
      "Edda Magnason",
      "Sverrir Gudnason",
      "Kjell Bergqvist"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no json here, because the result of `data.json()` will be a regular python object (in this case a dictionary). So `v` (i.e. value) is a dictionary and in the django templates the keys are available as attributes: `v.year`, for example.